# .resume is executed after calling other delegate methods

Tags: swift3

I have added my webservice call in `viewDidLoad()`,  but it always resumes the execution after all other functions are called. Below is my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {        
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addSlideMenuButton()        
    getData()        
    calendarManager = JTCalendarManager.init()
    calendarManager.delegate = self 
    createMinAndMaxDate()        
    calendarManager.menuView = calendarMenuView
    calendarManager.contentView = calendarContentView
}

func getData(){        
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http:xxx")!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, 
    response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }            
        else {                
            do{                    
                //empty eventDetail dictionary
                self.Detail = [String: String]() as NSDictionary

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: 
                data, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] {
                    if let nestedDictionary = 
                    dictionary["xxx_webservices"] as? [String: Any] 
                    {
                        // access nested dictionary values by key
                        let dateArray = nestedDictionary["3"] as! 
                        [String:Any]
                        for details in (dateArray["xxx"]  as! 
                        [[String:Any]] ){
                            // access all key / value pairs in 
                         dictionary
                            print(details["xxx"]!)

                                DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: { 
                                () -> Void in
                                    //event details contains details 
                                    of an event
                                    self.eventDetail = 
                                     nestedDictionary["3"] as! 
                                     NSDictionary
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
            catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }                
        }            
    }
    task.resume()
```

`task.resume()` always executes after calling delegates of calendar method. How can I resume the task before calling other delegates so that I can have data to be displayed in the calendar view? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code in the web service did the trick.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.calendarManager.reload()
}
```

This will call the calendar delegates with the web service data.